# How to convert nested object from one type to another

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, mapping

I have a C# object with structure like

```
class Source 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Source> Children {get; set;}
}
```

I want to convert an object of type `Source` (with unknown number of `Children`) to object of type `Destination`

```
class Destination
{
    public int key {get; set;}
    public List<Destination> nodes {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way I can do this using `LINQ` or do I have to loop through all and map it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something recursive like this:

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Source> Children { get; set; }

    public Destination GetDestination()
    {
        return new Destination
        {
            nodes = Children.Select(c => c.GetDestination()).ToList(),
            key = Id
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `ForEach` you can just do a `Select` and a `ToList` and set it right in the initializer.  That would be a more Linq way of doing this.  But the important part is the recursion.

Comment: You don't need to to new up a list.  Just set the return of `ToList` to nodes and it will work.

Comment: Thanks k4rlsson and @juharr for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
    List<A> alist = new List<A>();
    List<B> blist = alist.Select(a => new B()).ToList();


    public class A
    {}

    public class B
    {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a constructor to the Destination class that accepts a Source as a parameter:

```
class Destination
{
    public int key {get; set;}
    public List<Destination> nodes {get; set;}

    public Destination(Source source)
    {
        Key = source.Id;
        Nodes = source.Select(s => new Destination(s)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
var destinations = sources.Select(s => new Destination(s)).ToList();
```

This could run forever maybe, haven't tried it.